# Socketio: Incorrect data is receiving in listener while sending bunch of calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am currently bringing Socket.io in my own project, in which I am replacing my existing node.js request and response with socket now, I am using socket connect like below.

**Client side**: client.js

```
 constructor( VaultServerURL ) {
   this.connection = io.connect();
}
 this.connection.emit("RestCall", {
   requestUniqueID: requestID,
   path: RequestPath,
   grpcRequestOptions: requestOptions
});

this.connection.on(requestID, function (data) {
   var result = data;
   // Some logics
});
```

**Server Side:** server.js

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {                

    socket.on('RestCall', function ( data ) {
    // ISSUE: Same data is getting for some calls
     that.socketRestHandler( data, that );
    });
});
```

In this, we will emit the request as “RestCall” which then listen in the server-side, I am getting issue in below scenario,

I will send first request as ‘/login’ which emit by my client.js with below attributes,

```
 this.connection.emit("RestCall", {
   requestUniqueID: ‘/login’+[timestamp],
   path: ‘/login’,
   grpcRequestOptions: {
    headers: //Login headers
   }
});
```

And this will receive by the server.js

```
socket.on('RestCall', function ( data ) {
    that.socketRestHandler( data);
});
```

This call works fine, but once we got login method response then, I will send other subsequent request like ‘/request1’, ‘/request2’, “/request3” which different headers and with different parameters as shown in below.

```
 this.connection.emit("RestCall", {
   requestUniqueID: ‘/request1+[timestamp],
   path: ‘/request1 ’,
   grpcRequestOptions: {
    headers: //request1 headers
   }
});

 this.connection.emit("RestCall", {
   requestUniqueID: ‘/request2+[timestamp],
   path: ‘/request2 ’,
   grpcRequestOptions: {
    headers: //request2 headers
   }
});

this.connection.emit("RestCall", {
   requestUniqueID: ‘/request3+[timestamp],
   path: ‘/request3 ’,
   grpcRequestOptions: {
    headers: //request3 headers
   }
});
```

The actual issue is in server.js listener side, for all three requests I am getting same grpcRequestOptions.headers like below

```
socket.on('RestCall', function ( data ) {
// ISSUE: Same data is getting for some calls
 that.socketRestHandler( data, that );
});
```

Here, data.grpcRequestOptions.headers is receiving same for all three calls (/request1, /request2, /request3) but other properties of data such as requestUniqueID, path are received correctly as expected like below.

**For Request 1:**

```
   requestUniqueID: ‘/request1+[timestamp],
   path: ‘/request1 ’,
   grpcRequestOptions: {
    headers: //request1 headers
   }
```

**For Request 2:**

```
   requestUniqueID: ‘/request2+[timestamp],
   path: ‘/request2 ’,
   grpcRequestOptions: {
    headers: //request1 headers
   }
```

**For Request 3:**

```
   requestUniqueID: ‘/request3+[timestamp],
   path: ‘/request3 ’,
   grpcRequestOptions: {
    headers: //request1 headers
   }
```

The issue here is when I sending a bunch of calls from the client to the server some of the properties of the data (socket data) are received identical (even though they are different while sending in client). Is this a known issue in socket io or am I missing something here?

Comment: how are you setting the headers property? Please show actual code not a story

Comment: While it could be an issue with Socket.io, I'd say it's very unlikely for something as simple as you described; given the library is actively maintained and widely used. The question is a little vague to me the way it's written. Could you update your question and share a minimal reproducible example (i.e. a code snippet that actually runs and demonstrates the problem you're facing)?